# Mapping String to String value

Tags: java, string, converters

Here is my problem:

I have list of possible `Product` categories(for example: `Shoes`,`Mode`,`Women`), and I need to convert this to my specific names.

example: I get the category `Women` and I need to convert this to `Lady's`.

I have about 40 category names that i need to convert.

My question is :What is the best way to do this in JAVA.

I thought about switch case, but i dont know is this a good solution.

```
switch (oldCategoryName) {
    case "Women":
        return "Ladys";
    default:
        return "Default";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the java `switch` does not work on `String` objects for java versions below 7.

You can store values in a map :

```
// storing
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Women", "Ladys");
// add other values

// retrieving
String ladys = map.get("Women");
```

Or you can also use a `.properties` file to store all those associations, and retrieve a property object.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("mapping.properties"));
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();
String ladys = props.getProperty("Women");
```

Comment: Many thanks, i will probably go with the property file solution. Its easiest to add new categories and make changes

Answer (score 3):

You can use static map for that.
Make a Static Map as below

```
public class PropertiesUtil {
    private static final Map<String, String> myMap;
    static {
        Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        aMap.put("Women", "Ladys");
        aMap.put("another", "anotherprop");
        myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(aMap);
    }
}
```

then get the replacing string..

```
String womenReplace = PropertiesUtil.myMap.get("Women");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using enums:

```
 public enum ProductsCategory {
        Mode("MyMode"),
        Shoes("MyShoes"); 

        private String name;

        private ProductsCategory(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Then the retrieval:

```
String myModeStr = ProductsCategory.Mode.getName();
```

Comment: Many thanks, i will probably go with the property file solution. Its easiest to add new categories and make changes